# Amazon S3 and Cloudfront with zip file problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am quite new to AWS and I am trying to upload zip file to s3 through web browser and use an application at Lambda unzip it. After the file have been unzip at s3, i use cloudfront to host the website as the index.html is in sub-folder. However, when i run the website on my browser, it appears as downloaded file with unknown type instead of showing the html content. Is there anything that i do wrong?

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>AWS S3 File Upload</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Serverless web application example">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/black.css">

    <!-- Theme used for syntax highlighting of codes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/monokai.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/esri/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ride.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/message.css">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
    <button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.region = 'region'; // 1. Enter your region

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'poolid' // 2. Enter your identity pool
    });

    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if (err) alert(err);
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
    });

    var bucketName = 'bucketname'; // Enter your bucket name
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: bucketName
        }
    });

    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
    var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {

        var file = fileChooser.files[0];

        if (file) {

            results.innerHTML = '';
            var objKey = file.name;
            var params = {
                Key: objKey,
                ContentType: file.type,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };

            bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
                } else {
                    listObjs();
                }
            });
        } else {
            results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
        }
    }, false);
    function listObjs() {
        var prefix = 'testing';
        bucket.listObjects({
            Prefix: prefix
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
            } else {
                var objKeys = "";
                data.Contents.forEach(function(obj) {
                    objKeys += obj.Key + "<br>";
                });
                results.innerHTML = objKeys;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
                
    <div id="authTokenModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="authToken">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Your Auth Token</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea class="authToken"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/reveal.js?2"></script>
        <script>
            // More info about config & dependencies:
            // - https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
            // - https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#dependencies
            Reveal.initialize({
                dependencies: [
                    { src: 'plugin/markdown/marked.js' },
                    { src: 'plugin/markdown/markdown.js' },
                    { src: 'plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true },
                    { src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true }
                ]
            });
        </script>
        <script>

            // More info https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
            Reveal.initialize({
                controls: true,
                progress: true,
                center: true,
                hash: true,

                transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom

                // More info https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#dependencies
                dependencies: [
                    { src: 'plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
                    { src: 'plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
                    { src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true },
                    { src: 'plugin/search/search.js', async: true },
                    { src: 'plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true },
                    { src: 'plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true }
                ]
            });

        </script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cognito-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="js/esri-map.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ride.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check the content type in S3 of your index.html

Comment: Please share the upload code and current S3 bucket settings.

Comment: I share the code below as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey you can edit your question and add the code in the question, instead of sharing it as an answer. Since many people cannot differentiate from the answer. Answer section is only for answers. So could you please delete that and include it in your question?

Comment: Okay. I have edited and moved the code to the questions. Thank you for telling

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up static web hosting in your S3 bucket to render html content.
Please check out [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).

Comment: So in addition to the CloudFront setup, I need to set up static web hosting on s3?